# MySQL sort by not sorting?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am fetching rows from my DB using this request:

```
SELECT * FROM {$db_sales} WHERE date = '{$date}' ORDER BY 'amount' DESC
```

So, obviously, i expected the returned values to be sorted in descending order by the amount column in my DB, but it doesn't? it still fetches them, but just doesn't sort them?

Any ideas here? is my SQL statement wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER BY clause uses column name.
Column name should not give in quotes.
there fore the query becomes as follows

```
SELECT * FROM {$db_sales} WHERE date = '{$date}' ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

remove single quote around amount like this and try:

```
SELECT * FROM {$db_sales} WHERE date = '{$date}' ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Comment: Is your "amount" type interger?

Answer (score 1):

Use below query

```
SELECT * FROM {$db_sales} WHERE date = '{$date}' ORDER BY amount DESC
```